# Git bash console on windows does not start

Tags: git, git-bash

While trying to start a git bash window on any folder in my windows 7 machine, the git bash window closes right away.

I do this by clicking on the "Git Bash" option in the context menu.

[image]

When I try to start the Git Bash the console window starts temporarily for a few seconds and exits with a 
'logout' message.

I tried to go to the Git installed location and run the "Git Bash.lnk" which exits with this message:

```
D:\DevProgs\Installed\Git-1.7.11\Git>"Git Bash.lnk"
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.11-preview20120710)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

AD@AYUSMAN /
$ logout

D:\DevProgs\Installed\Git-1.7.11\Git>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I had been able to use Git Bash without any issues on any folder so far.

System Info:
Windows 7 64 bit professional edition.
Git 1.7.11

Answer (score 5):

This suddently started happening for me also. I upgraded to Git version 1.9.5 but nothing changed.

The shortcut was using the following command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` and exiting with this bad-looking guru meditation:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin> .\sh.exe
0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x68570000, RegionSize 0x460000, State 0x10000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe:
*** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

So I changed the shortcut to launch Bash instead: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i` and all was fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this by:

1. Open CMD as Admin
2. CD to the installation path of GitHub (e.g. CMDPRMPT> CD "C:\Program Files\Git")
3. Run "git-bash.exe" from command prompt
4. Right-click the GIT BASH icon on the taskbar and pin it so you can avoid steps 1-3 in the future.

OS Version: Windows 7

GIT version: 2.15.0

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is just how to put the gitbash icon on the taskbar. That's not at all relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

just open  git-Bash.exe as admin this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try git v1.8.4 for windows, it works fine to me.
It seems newer version can't use https git push.

Comment: will it not be a problem if I can't use the https push?

Comment: @Ayusman I am just give a suggestion, because push via https is a very important feature for me, I am not sure is it important for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my Kaspersky antivirus. I had to re-install Git and add the Git exe (and other associated Git executable) to safe list of Kaspersky safe list. It took quitesometime to work, but seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That problem, although showing always the same face (`git-bash` just not starting), can obviously occur due to many reasons. In my case, none of the other solutions helped; I had re-installed Git for Windows a dozen times to no avail. I was using version 2.42.

During those installations, I had chosen `mintty` as terminal, because the alternative `cmd` is just not usable IMHO. Finally, I uninstalled Git for Windows again and examined my user profile directory (that Git bash considers to be the home directory). I noticed that there was a `.minttyrc` configuration file even after having uninstalled Git for Windows.

After having deleted that file and after having re-installed Git for Windows, `git-bash` was working as expected. Obviously, `.minttyrc` was damaged to a degree that it prevented `mintty` (and hence, `git-bash`) from starting.

That also explains why `git-bash` may run when started in administrator context, and may not run when started in normal user context: The profile directory is different for each user. `Administrator`'s home directory may contain a valid `.minttyrc`, while another user profile might contain a damaged one.

**Bottom line:**

- When uninstalling (or upgrading) Git for Windows, it may leave damaged `.minttyrc` files in users' profile directories (that is, in users' home directories from a bash point of view).
- The damage may prevent `git-bash` from starting.
- Hence, if none of the previous solutions helps, just delete the `.minttyrc` file in the profile directory of the user in whose context `git-bash.exe` should start; normally, that directory is `c:\Users\<username>`.

Note that you do not need to uninstall and re-install Git for Windows to see the effect. Please also note that deleting `.minttyrc` will destroy the settings if you already have configured `mintty` to your needs. However, that configuration is extremely easy and takes only a few seconds.